# Was operator for sprint field

Tags: jira

I am looking for a way to track issues that are being added and removed form an active sprint. So far I have been doing this with a general jira report at the beginning and end of a sprint, then checking for any changes. However this is cumbersome. For many other fields, the was operator can be used, but not for the sprint field. Is there a way to emulate the behavior of `was` in jql, or is a history of which issues were stored in a sprint at a certain point in time not stored by jira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Scrum Boards, JIRA contains a "Sprint Report" out of the box.

This will show you all issues in the sprint, which ones are completed, which ones were added after the sprint started (marked by an asterisk) and also lists the issues that were removed from the sprint.

For a bit more info, you can check the documentation [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/sprint-report-777002722.html).